# 'not a single-group group function' in oracle when using LISTAGG

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

My query is using LISTAGG and it is showing an error 00937. 00000 -  "not a single-group group function"
I have gone through many stackoverflow questions similar to this error and those answers are using some subquery for resolving the issue. I don't want to write a subquery in this query

```
SELECT DISTINCT AMD.UNID AS APPLICATION_REF_ID, 
LISTAGG(LOC.PLT,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY LOC.PLT ) AS MYLOC  
FROM TAB1 AMD
LEFT JOIN TAB2 PER
ON NVL (AMD.PERMITNEWID, AMD.PERMITID) = PER.UNID
LEFT JOIN TAB3 LOC
ON NVL(AMD.PERMITNEWID, AMD.PERMITID) = LOC.PERMITID
WHERE NVL (AMD.PERMITNEWID, AMD.PERMITID) = PER.UNID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a missing `group by`, you don't need `distinct()` if you are grouping by `UNID`

```
SELECT AMD.UNID AS APPLICATION_REF_ID, 
LISTAGG(LOC.PLT,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY LOC.PLT ) AS MYLOC  
FROM TAB1 AMD
LEFT JOIN TAB2 PER
ON NVL (AMD.PERMITNEWID, AMD.PERMITID) = PER.UNID
LEFT JOIN TAB3 LOC
ON NVL(AMD.PERMITNEWID, AMD.PERMITID) = LOC.PERMITID
WHERE NVL (AMD.PERMITNEWID, AMD.PERMITID) = PER.UNID
GROUP BY AMD.UNID
```

Comment: This is working.Thanks, Is it possible to get distinct LOC.PLT values for aggregation?

Comment: its giving an error 'result of string concatenation is too long'

Comment: I have more join statements in my query.

Comment: you need to move this in a subquery, and join

Answer (score 1):

Try with group by:

```
SELECT amd.unid AS application_ref_id,
       LISTAGG (loc.plt, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY loc.plt) AS myloc
  FROM tab1 amd
       LEFT JOIN tab2 per ON NVL (amd.permitnewid, amd.permitid) = per.unid
       LEFT JOIN tab3 loc
           ON NVL (amd.permitnewid, amd.permitid) = loc.permitid
 WHERE NVL (amd.permitnewid, amd.permitid) = per.unid
GROUP BY amd.unid
```